# How to access a Javascript object in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have a (ES6 style) Javascript class in a file. I import it into HTML with the script tag (i even used the `type="module"` attribute). (first i used a main.js file and import the file with the class there)

```
export default class Gameboard {

    constructor(elementId) {
        this.gameboardElement = document.getElementById(elementId);
    }

    ... some methods
}
```

The object has some other methods that I would like to test in the browser console (Chrome or Firefox). But when I try to instantiate it in the console I get an error:

```
let gb = new Gameboard();
Uncaught ReferenceError: GameBoard is not defined
```

I try to import it first with the import statement, but it doesn't work in the console. I get an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Is this even possible what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer to my question.

It is not directly possible to access variables and objects in the console, unless you enter the debug mode in the sources tab. You have to set a breakpoint in the Javascript code. After running the code, the execution stops at the breakpoint and you can use all the variables in the console which were instantiated to this point.

Source: [Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `window.foo` inside your module and access it in the chrome console as just `foo`.